# How to limit number of simultaneous connections per port in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I have VPN running on port 2020 (I'm connected to VPN in my mobile and so this connection is always established, even started a huge file to have one connection always for being sure), and want to limit the number of simultaneous connections to this port.

I saw https://serverfault.com/questions/1039959/how-do-i-limit-simultaneous-connections-to-a-port-with-ufw and added the rules which should be added to `/etc/ufw/after.rules` and then I did reload `ufw`.

The issue is it seems it does not work, because I tried this simple commands from another server (100 lines of it in fact):

```
curl -v server_ip_v4:2020 &
curl -v server_ip_v4:2020 &
curl -v server_ip_v4:2020 &
curl -v server_ip_v4:2020 &
```

But I get response from `curl`.

Do you guide me how to limit port connections?

Comment: Assuming the application does the usual thing, listens on this port and forks processes (or uses threads) to deal with incoming connections, the simple way is to just limit it inside the application. Or put a load balancer in front, where you can configure these kind of things.

Comment: @dirkt in fact application is VPN, and in my mobile I start downloading a huge file while VPN is connected. And I try to curl from other server. I see meanwhile download speed is not getting lower even for a second. Am I doing right?

Comment: Please edit your question and add some details: What VPN, how have you configured it? What computer is it running on, where do you do the downloads from (WLAN?). Is the curl connection going over VPN? We cannot guess those things. You probably need some traffic priorization, and not a limit on connections...